# Qstring:find method counterpart in qt4 Qstring class

Tags: qt, qt4

I am porting some code in qt3, I can not find the find method for QT4 Qstring class. what is the counter part for the qt3's Qstring::find method. which one method should I use?

Answer (score 0):

[QString::indexOf()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#indexOf). The [Qt 3 support page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring-qt3.html#find-2) for QString (linked from the QString main page) documents this.